# How to count matches on a stream filter?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

How can I count the matches of a stream filter? I'm trying to refactor the following code to java8 `stream`:

```
//java7
int i = 0;
for (Node node : response.getNodes()) {
    Integer id = node.getId();
    if (id != null) {
        node.setContent("This is the id: " + id);
        i++;
    }
}

//java8
response.getNodes().stream()
    .filter(node -> node.getId() != null)
    .forEach(node -> node.setValue("This is the id: " + node.getId()));
```

How can I now get the count of filtered elements that were applied?
Sidequestion: in the old code I can reuse the `Integer id` multiple times. How can I achieve the same with streams?

Comment: why not to add external variable as counter and just add increment operation at the `forEach`?

Comment: @nikis That would not work with a local variable, because variables captured from the environment that you use in a lambda must be effectively final. So it would be more cumbersome than you think.

Comment: @Jesper @nikis you could use a `LongAdder` instance and keep incrementing that.  That class was added to Java 8 for just this purpose.

Comment: @Jesper your comment made me to take a deeper look on Java 8 features, I spent too much time outside `Java` kingdom at the `C# LINQ` heaven =)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Since `setValue` is a side-effect function, you can use `peek`:

```
long i = response.getNodes()
                 .stream()
                 .filter(node -> node.getId() != null)
                 .peek(node -> node.setValue("This is the id: " + node.getId()))
                 .count();
```

I'm not a fan of this approach because peak is meant to use for debugging purpose (this would do the trick). Note that in Java 9, `count()` may be able to not execute the stream pipeline if it can compute the count directly from the source (I don't think it's the case here, since you apply a filtering but it's good to keep it in mind).

> Sidequestion: in the old code I can reuse the Integer id multiple
>   times. How can I achieve the same with streams?

It depends on your use-case, since the API doesn't have tuples your best chance is to create a class, let's say `Tuple2`, so that you can map each node to a new tuple and reuse the id.

Something like:

```
.stream().map(node -> new Tuple2<>(node, node.getId()).moreStreamOps(...);
                                                      ^
                                                      |
                 at that point you have a Stream<Tuple2<Node, Integer>> 
                 from which you can grab the id with Tuple2#getSecond
```

In your case, if you stay with a stream of nodes, you can just grab the id with `getId()` at any time.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I will then stick to the "old" approach as these kind of side effects are probably not meant for use with stream api.

Comment: @membersound Well if you are aware of what you are doing it's not a problem. You can't always avoid side-effects as Java is not a functional language anyway (even with its bunch of new features).

Comment: You could probably split up the task into two differnt stream operations: The first sets the id using forEach(), the second counts the nodes using count().

Comment: @isnot2bad Yes this is what I usually do/recommend if you need 2 terminal operations (and that performance is not a concern nor something you need to optimize for the moment), but in this case, `forEach` is likely the same as `peek`, so it's fine to do it in a single pass.

Comment: @AlexisC. You're right. But forEach feels more correct to me somehow - although effectively there is no difference. Probably they should rename `peek` into `forEachAndThen` just to get rid of the bad feeling... ;)

Comment: @isnot2bad: that would be misleading. `forEach` does what it says, it applies the action to every element. In contrast, `peek` applies the action to the elements seen while performing the actual terminal operation. In other words, if the actual terminal operation is *short circuiting*, `peek` might miss elements. Further, it might be implementation-dependent. E.g. if the terminal operation is `count`, it might skip elements if it can predict the count without processing them (the current implementation of `count` will process all elements but that behavior is under discussion).